Linked object and rig without keyframes
I have made a model, a rig for the model and several actions for it through the action editor.
Then I have made a new Blender file and linked the collection of the model and rig from the first file into the new one.
My problem is that it seems that the animation in my first file's playback is also copied and I can edit my playback or NLA editor in my new file.
Is there a way to link a character and all its actions to a new file but to still be able to set the timeline and NLA editor in the new file?
(I read about a feature called "make proxy" but I can't find it. Was that a feature that was deprecated in Blender 4.2? And if not is that what I should use here?)
